# Append Form Fields with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fieldset

When using Javascript to add additional form fields dyanamically that are contained in a single fieldset, I am running into the issue of the closing fieldset tag still be applying after the first form field. This is causing the layout to break and I need to figure out how I can work around that.

I tried to move the closing fieldset tag outside of the DIV where the additional fields are being appended to, but Firebug inspection still shows it as closing after the first item.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function()
{
    var template = $('#inventoryItems .inventory:first').clone(),
        inventoryCount = 1;

    var addInventory = function()
    {
        inventoryCount++;
        var inventory = template.clone().find(':input').each(function()
        {
            var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + inventoryCount;
            $(this).prev().attr('for', newId); // update label for (assume prev sib is label)
            this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
        }).end() // back to .attendee
        .attr('id', 'inv' + inventoryCount) // update attendee id
        .appendTo('#inventoryItems'); // add to container
    };

    $('.btnAddInventory').click(addInventory); // attach event
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
                    <div id="inventoryItems" class="inventoryItems" style="margin:0; padding:0;">

                        <fieldset style="width:62%; float:left; margin-left: 19%;">

                            <div id="inv1" class="inventory">
                                <label>Inventory</label>
                                <select name="invItem" style="width:92%;">
                                    <?php
                                        $invItem_values = array("id", "name");
                                        display_options_list($dp_conn, $invItem_values, "inventory", "id");
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                                <a class="btnAddInventory"><img src="images/icn_new_article.png"></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/icn_trash.png"></a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        </fieldset><div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your HTML markup, an extra closing DIV tag, right before the closing FIELDSET tag. Move it after the `.clear` tag and you should be ok.

When parsing your HTML and encountering the closing DIV tag (which corresponds to `#inventoryItems`), it notices you still have a FIELDSET tag that is open so it inserts the close tag for it. Afterwards, when encountering the actual closing FIELDSET tag, it is simply ignored, because there are no open FIELDSET tags.

The original error is in your JS code. The following line adds to the DIV #inventoryItems instead of the FIELDSET.

```
    .appendTo('#inventoryItems'); // add to container
```

Try replacing it with:

```
    .appendTo('#inventoryItems > fieldset'); // add to fieldset
```

Comment: The closing DIV is correct but as I mentioned in my original post, I tried moving the closing Fieldset outside of it since I was trying to append other fields before that. I went ahead and moved it back but it is still pretty much the same case with the closing Fieldset being set before the appended fields. Thank you though!

Comment: Ah perfect, that is exactly what was missing. My inexperience with Javascript strikes again but I greatly appreciate the help resolving this!